# HTML Image Maps do not work in OSX Mail?

Tags: html, image, email, dictionary

Running *OS X Mavericks 10.9.2*. Have the following code in an *e-mail*:

```
<img src="..." usemap="#144c9d10b3cc3146_map">
<map name="144c9d10b3cc3146_map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="100,1322,613,1338" href="..." target="_blank">
    <area shape="rect" coords="100,1337,613,1353" href="..." target="_blank">
</map>
```

Works perfectly in web *Gmail*, but in *OSX Mail*, I can't click on any of the links. Any ideas? Should I convert to *CSS* absolute elements?

Comment: This likely won't work in most non-web-based email clients, not just OSX Mail.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a solution that works in most email clients then you'll need to avoid a *lot* of HTML techniques. CSS isn't well supported and image maps are definitely not.

I'm afraid the most reliable way to do this for all clients, including Microsoft Outlook, is to use traditional table-based layout techniques. Most commercial HTML emails you receive are laid out in this way.

If your HTML skills don't date back as far as the pre-CSS "table layout" days then you can automatically export image slices as HTML tables in most versions of Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use **Default** `<img usemap="#map">` and `<map name="map">` change it. Like `<img usemap="#mapLink">` and `<map name="mapLink">`. It's working !!!

Answer (score -1):

Put your map just inside the closing body tag.

Comment: Works. Using Apple Mail Version 7.3